# How do I draw a vermiculated line in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, draw, spline

I know how to draw straight lines but could I draw a line which (around a straight line i.e.)?

[image: spline]

Excuse me, I do not speak English very well to describe this more detailed ;-)

Edit: Hey sorry for my late answer - you are right, it should be something like a sine wave which "vericulates" and looks like a worm "coiling" (right word?) around a simple spline/curve (drawn by the user).

The "Noise" version looks a bit too random.

The wave should look like the above image.

Comment: The term I think you are looking for is "spline" which is a curve based on vertices that curves a around them like a worm, thus vermiculating. ("vermiculate" is actually a fine English word, but is very rarely used)

Comment: what graphics library are you using?

Comment: could you draw an example in say, paint, and upload it here to your question?

Comment: so, what's still missing from the answers?

Answer (score 4):

why not draw a sine wave?

Answer (score 0):

Java 2D examples of splines can be found at http://ibiblio.org/e-notes/Splines/Intro.htm

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [PerlinNoise](http://www.fundza.com/rman_shaders/noise/index.html), but applied to a line for a *hand-drawn* look (see 'Drawing sketched lines' on [this page](http://www.game-developers.org/node/174?page=1)...?

Answer (score 0):

Hey sorry for my late answer - you are right, it should be something like a sine wave which "vericulates" and looks like a worm "coiling" (right word?) around a simple spline/curve (drawn by the user).

The "Noise" version looks a bit too random.

The wave should look like this:
[Image](http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/2320/path3003.png)

Comment: This information should be an update to your question. I've moved it so you can delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Curve API (CAPI) (http://sourceforge.net/projects/curves/).
As they describe in their site, you will find there: implementation of various mathematical curves that define themselves over a set of control points. The curves supported are: Bezier, B-Spline, Cardinal Spline, Catmull-Rom Spline, Lagrange, Natural Cubic Spline, and NURBS.

If you have a defined set of points for the curve you want to draw, I fully recommend Cardinal-Spline or a more general B-spline. This API is quite well implemented.